# I have a table in that one row is PublishingStatus which is as Approved,Pending,Rejected

Tags: c#, sql-server, auto-update

[image: this is the image of my table]

The table I'm saving it as  Approve=1, Pending=0, Rejected=2, and another row is ApprovalDeadlineDate. If the approval deadline date is expired(crosses today's date) then it should auto-update and  publishing status should be approved that is '1'.

The query I'm using is below

```
update Tbl_Documents set
  PublishingStatus = case when Convert(nvarchar(20),cast(ApprovalDeadlinedate as date),105) < Convert(nvarchar(20),cast(SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+05:30') as date),105)
    then '1' else '0' end
```

Comment: please update question with the query and not in comment. Also some sample data and expected result please. And please also format your query to readable form

Comment: Asking for help with any sort of urgency, priority etc is not allowed on SO. Volunteers will contribute when they have a chance. If you want it looked at quicker then ensure you ask a good quality question. Which for example means putting data in as text NOT images.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
UPDATE Tbl_Documents SET PublishingStatus = '1'
WHERE CAST(ApprovalDeadlinedate AS DATE) < GETDATE()
AND PublishingStatus = '0'
```